# Java Client not able to establish SSL handshake with server

Tags: ssl, certificate, java

I have a Java client which is using the Apache HttpClient 4.1 library to make an HTTPs request to a server which doesn't require authentication. If I call that server with my browser or curl, the request is accepted. However from my Java client, I see the following (when debug is turned on)...

```
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
 main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110
 main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

So it seems my client did the handshake in TLSv1 but then sent an SSLv2 ClientHello which the server didn't seem to like. According to [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34827/why-clients-offer-handshaking-with-ssl-2-0-protocol) it seems the server should not reject an SSLv2 ClientHello. Could it be something specific about this server that is making it reject this ClientHello?

I also noticed the below log output at the beginning of establishing the connection....

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=Secure Global CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
```

And then it goes on to add various entities as "trusted cert"s.

And the final exception I noticed was...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

So could it be a problem with the certificate (or lack of) on my (client) side? But according to [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110621/ssl-newbie-does-https-client-also-need-a-certificate) I thought the client was not required to provide a certificate.

Bottom line is I am not clear if the root of the problem is the SSLv2 Client Hello or the certs or both?

Comment: And how is this related to security? I'd recommend to move this to programming.

Comment: I was debating where to put it but I chose here because the crux of the matter is why a server would reject a SSLv2 Client Hello (posts here indicate it shouldn't) and does a client need its own cert (posts here also indicate it doesn't).

Comment: Normally a client does not need a certificate.  I would rule out a SSL/TLS protocol mismatch first.  Go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and enter your server's hostname, and this tool will tell you which SSL/TLS protocols your server supports.  Then, do a GET request from your Java client to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html, and this should tell you which SSL/TLS protocols your client supports.

Comment: If you are able to make an HTTPS request to the server from cURL or a regular browser, then this proves that the server is not looking for a client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like you. This is how I solved it. It may not cater to your exact problem, but give it a try.

```
SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```